# Getting list of _all_ methods in a class for a TestNG test suite

Tags: java, testng

I am writing a suite logger for TestNG and I am having trouble retrieving a complete list of all methods for a `class` in a test suite. The `getAllMethods()` method on the `ISuite interface` only gives me the methods annotated by `@Test`. I have several public methods on my `class` that are annotated with `@BeforeClass`, `@AfterClass` and so on. I want to retrieve those methods as well. How do I access them? There is nothing in `ISuite` that seems to do what I want.

Comment: Do you want it before the suite is run?

Comment: Yes. I want to print a summary of the suite in the log that lists tests, classes for each test and then the configuration methods for each class and the test methods for each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perhaps use the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to get all the methods, members and filter it out as well.